# Error, Problema con XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

Tengo este código en PHP :

```
<?php 
    include ('parametros.php');
    $conexion = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);

    if (!$conexion) {
        echo "hay pedo";
    }else{
        echo "puro fierro :v";
    }
 ?>
```

Al momento de entrar al navegador, me da este error :

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'yo'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\
>   Back End - Alumnos\cesar\php\logica\conexion.php on line 6
>   Connection failed: Access denied for user 'yo'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES))

(Ni con ese usuario ni con *root* con el password ' ')

Cuando veo el *MySql* aparece esto así :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mis compañeros tienen lo de la imagen en letras negras, a mi me aparecen en rojo.

He buscado la solución y no me ha funcionado. Además de como buscar ese tipo de error.

PHP 7

Comment: puedes escribir los parámetros que tienes ?

Comment: @gama984 claro: define("DB_SERVER", 'localhost');
define("DB_USERNAME", 'root');
define("DB_PASSWORD", '');
define("DB_DATABASE", 'db_curso');

Comment: Por seguridad le recomiendo que le agregue una contraseña al servidor localhost  al que tiene el usuario root y le agregas esa contraseña a los parámentros de conexión

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El usuario que intentas usar para conectarte a mysql, no existe, la contraseña es incorrecta, o no tiene permitido el acceso desde localhost.

puedes cambiar de usuario o en caso que no exista crear el usuario con la contraseña que tienes definida en DB_PASSWORD.

para lo anterior ejecuta en phpmyadmin:

```html
CREATE USER 'yo'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'yo'@'localhost';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'yo'@'localhost';
```

Si el el valor de DB_PASSWORD es "mypassword"
y la pagina esta alojada en el mismo servidor que el servidor mysql.
lo anterior deba funcionar.

Otra opcion segun la imagen que del phpmyadmin es usar el usuario cualquiera sin password.

Comment: no me soluciona el error, sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: cual es el valor de las constantes **DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE** ?

Comment: 'localhost', 'yo', '123', db_curso (esto creando el user como me has recomendado)

Comment: Supongo que cambiaste el password de la instrucción que te dé su por **123** si no la contraseña es **mypassword**.

Comment: borré el que hice y puse el 'mypassword', sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Tu página está en el mismo servidor que MySQL?

Comment: no sé cómo saberlo, estoy iniciando y ese término me es desconocido, pero imagino que si.

Comment: Segun la imagen que pusiste parece que si pero no usas el puerto por defecto añade el puerto al constructor de mysqli **mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE, 33065)**

Comment: Eso solucionó mi error. Gracias, esto le podrá servir a alguien más. }

Answer (score 0):

Trata esto.

```
    <?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxx');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'sample_db');
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) or die("Error " . mysqli_error());
$database = mysqli_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error());
mysqli_set_charset("utf8",$connection);
?>
```

Y te recomiendo que uses pdo, recuerda que las versiones de php influye mucho.

Comment: Me trae esto: Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Back End - Alumnos\cesar\php\logica\parametros.php on line 8
Error

Answer (score 0):

La solución que encontré para mi caso fue:

```
include ('parametros.php');
    $conexion = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE,1512);
```

Como pueden ver, agregué "1512" que fue el nuevo puerto que agregué al configurar el Xamp.